# Mozilla Firefox suddenly not visible and freezes PC

Tags: 20.04, firefox

Firefox has been working fine on my computer for years now. All of a sudden it refuses to work.

When I click on the Firefox shortcut and try to open the browser, it launches but nothing is seen. When I hit the 'All Applications' key on the keyboard, this is what I see:

[image]

On the left is what is supposed to be Firefox.

It seems to be taking up lots of processor resources. Like when Firefox is in the foreground, the computer hangs and I can't do anything else. It feels as if a script on one of the open webpages has entered an infinite loop and is blocking the processor.

The Firefox browser contains a lot of precious bookmarks and history. Is there a way for me to recover this, and also to get Firefox to work without re-installing it?

Comment: Might get answers here. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/

Answer (score 1):

Try opening Firefox in safe mode.

Open a terminal and type

```
firefox -safe-mode
```

Make sure you have closed all instances of Firefox before running this command.

If it runs successfully, create a Firefox Account from which you can recreate your bookmarks which will be available to you on any future logins.

For reference, Firefox stores your Bookmarks, Passwords and other data in the hidden directory .mozilla so may still be accessible without even opening FF.

See [this reference](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data) for more information about where to find the files.

Having saved the files to a new safe location, it will be open to you to re-install FF to resolve any issues.

> Is there a way for me to recover this, and also to get Firefox to work
> without re-installing it?

The sensible thing may well be to preserve what you can now since there may be an inevitability that Firefox (or perhaps more) will need to be re-installed to restore your installation to good health but creation of a Firefox account at any stage in this or after this processs will save you much trouble later on.

Comment: Kill all instances of firefox for all users, then try it again.   Running instance of firefox may not match updated version of files on hard drive due to recent update