# Firefox became all blurry, white, and flickering

Tags: firefox, browser

I can't get Firefox to work. This is what it looks like when I start it:

[image]

I tried purging it. I removed all Firefox data on my profile by emptying the .mozilla folder.

```
sudo apt-get purge firefox
```

I then tried to create another Ubuntu profile and ran it there: it worked. It also worked fine on my profile when I ran it in safe-mode.

```
firefox --safe-mofe
```

But for the life of me I cannot get it to work under my usual profile, except under that mode. I do not understand why.

Do you have an idea of what would cause such a strange behavior?
By the way, I'm using 20.04.2LTS and Firefox got upgraded to 89.0. (I think it upgraded yesterday, and it might have been its first launch this morning, although it *did* work yesterday.)

Comment: Does [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1329665/307670) provide any help?

Comment: Obviously something strange happened to a setting, file, or whatever under `~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxxx.default`. You can try to find out which one is wrong by trial and error. Or if you don't mind using everything related to Firefox (bookmarks, history, settings, cookies, saved passwords, addons and their settings, etc. etc. etc.) you can just kill all Firefox processes, rename this directory and restart Firefox with brand new configuration.

Comment: That was my first line of thought too. That is why I completely removed everything that was under `.mozilla`. However, and that is why it's strange, I still get the same result, even upon removing and reinstalling firefox. Weirder yet, it works fine on a fresh Ubuntu profile. My guess is there must some sort of conflict with another configuration file from another application. But that's all I have and I don't know where to look.

Comment: "_tried to create another Ubuntu profile_". Do you mean another system (Linux) user? If so, can it be related to Gnome settings (Themes) of your current user? You can try to make the "other" user's Gnome settings _similar_ to your current user's and see what happens.

Comment: Delete the ~/.cache/mozilla/firefox folder. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema No, that was not the problem (and I had already tried that). I wrote the solution below.

Comment: Thanks for figuring out which setting causes that. There's also an issue open on Firefox's bug tracker for it: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1714483

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I have done some tedious trial and error by attempting to recreate the problem. I suceeded.
This bug has nothing to do with Firefox profiles, so if you run into that same problem, don't delete yours. Actually, it has to do with a conflict between Nvidia and the new version of Firefox.

[The Nvidia box responsible for the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3NR0.png)

If you encounter that problem:

- Run `nvidia-settings`
- Go to Antialiasing settings
- Uncheck "Enable FXAA" (like on the image)

I can't remember why I activated that option in the first place (maybe for OBS, DaVinci, or Kdenlive stuff?), but anyway for now everything is fine.

If you want to check out the bug (to send a ticket?), just check the box (you'll need an Nvidia graphic card, of course).

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. I'm not totally convinced it's not a FF bug though when it seems to be the only app that has the issue.